# TypeError: cloneDeep.cloneDeep is not a function (or _ is not defined)

Tags: javascript

So I'm [using lodash](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash.clonedeep) in a Node.js app, not Angular.

```
var cloneDeep = require('lodash.clonedeep');
var original = [...];
var newOne = cloneDeep.cloneDeep(original);
```

> TypeError: cloneDeep.cloneDeep is not a function

switching over to

```
var newOne = _.cloneDeep(original);
```

> _ is not defined

package.json

```
{
  ...
  "dependencies": {
    "lodash.clonedeep": "^4.5.0"
  }
}
```

VSC and Windows 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it based on this [sample](https://flaviocopes.com/how-to-clone-javascript-object/)

> var newOne = cloneDeep(original);